# -Xlint in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

What can I do to receive in my Eclipse warnings like these from O'Reilly's book titled "Java Generics and Collections"? :

```
% javac -Xlint:unchecked l/Stack.java l/ArrayStack.java \
%    l/Stacks.java l/Client.java
l/ArrayStack.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E)
as a member of the raw type java.util.List
    public void push(Object elt) list.add(elt);
                                          ^
1 warning
```

This is whole code which throws above warning:

```
l/Stack.java:
interface Stack {
   public boolean empty();
   public void push(Object elt);
   public Object pop();
}

l/ArrayStack.java:
import java.util.*;
class ArrayStack implements Stack {
   private List list;
   public ArrayStack() { list = new ArrayList(); }
   public boolean empty() { return list.size() == 0; }
   public void push(Object elt) { list.add(elt); }
   public Object pop() {
      Object elt = list.remove(list.size()-1);
      return elt;
   }
   public String toString() { return "stack"+list.toString(); }
}

l/Stacks.java:
class Stacks {
   public static Stack reverse(Stack in) {
      Stack out = new ArrayStack();
      while (!in.empty()) {
         Object elt = in.pop();
         out.push(elt);
      }
      return out;
   }
}

l/Client.java:
class Client {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Stack stack = new ArrayStack();
      for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) stack.push(new Integer(i));
      assert stack.toString().equals("stack[0, 1, 2, 3]");
      int top = ((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue();
      assert top == 3 && stack.toString().equals("stack[0, 1, 2]");
      Stack reverse = Stacks.reverse(stack);
      assert stack.empty();
      assert reverse.toString().equals("stack[2, 1, 0]");
   }
}
```

By the way I have more than 1 warning in this code when I compile it in Eclipse.

Maybe warnings of type `% javac -Xlint:unchecked ...` are displayed in Eclipse but I don't know where they are.

I don't see them in bookmarks either "Problems" or "Console".

Comment: You'll get unchecked warnings highlighted right in the editor, applied as adornments in the Package Navigator, and listed in Problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has its own Java compiler and doesn't use 'javac' so it doesn't produce the same warning messages.

When using the Eclipse IDE all the messages produced are configured in the Preferences in Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings.

You can also use the Eclipse compiler from the command line. The options for this are given [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm)